# Trying to set register to negative value causes SEGFAULT

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Are registers not allowed to be set to negative values? I figured that it would just set it to the maximum value if I set the register to -1. `mov eax, -1` causes a segmentation fault:

**main.nasm:**

```
BITS 32

              org     0x08048000

ehdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Ehdr
              db      0x7F, "ELF", 1, 1, 1, 0         ;   e_ident
      times 8 db      0
              dw      2                               ;   e_type
              dw      3                               ;   e_machine
              dd      1                               ;   e_version
              dd      _start                          ;   e_entry
              dd      phdr - $$                       ;   e_phoff
              dd      0                               ;   e_shoff
              dd      0                               ;   e_flags
              dw      ehdrsize                        ;   e_ehsize
              dw      phdrsize                        ;   e_phentsize
              dw      1                               ;   e_phnum
              dw      0                               ;   e_shentsize
              dw      0                               ;   e_shnum
              dw      0                               ;   e_shstrndx

ehdrsize      equ     $ - ehdr

phdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Phdr
              dd      1                               ;   p_type
              dd      0                               ;   p_offset
              dd      $$                              ;   p_vaddr
              dd      $$                              ;   p_paddr
              dd      filesize                        ;   p_filesz
              dd      filesize                        ;   p_memsz
              dd      5                               ;   p_flags
              dd      0x1000                          ;   p_align

phdrsize      equ     $ - phdr

_start:
              mov     eax, -1
              xor     al, al
              inc     al
              xor     bl, bl
              int     80h

filesize      equ     $ - $$
```

**These are my compilation commands:**

```
nasm -f bin -o main main.nasm
chmod +x main
```

Comment: It is failing because after you move -1 to EAX you do nothing to exit your program so it continues executing memory that is likely filled with zeroes. At some point it will likely hit an instruction like `add [eax], al`.Since EAX as a memory address will be in memory you don't have privileges to write it fails. Add a Linux 32-bit system call to exit using`int 0x80`

Comment: I did bother to try gdb but it didn't produce any response that I could make sense of. I apologize for my lack of experience. I have edited my example with an exit call. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Regarding your edit: The reason the exit fails is because the system call number is a 32-bit value in EAX. When you do `xor al, al` you zero out the lower byte only. The upper 24-bits will still be all 1s because you moved -1 to EAX ahead of it. Replace `xor     al, al
              inc     al` with `mov eax, 1` A value of one in EAX is the exit system call.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I don't know where I read it, but somewhere I had read that the system call only read the 8-bit `al` register. Clearly, that information was false. Thank you!

Comment: You probably confuse it with the exit code which is just the low 8 bits of `ebx` (`bl`).

Comment: You could have used `strace ./a.out` to debug this.  You'd see the `ENOSYS` return value from `int 0x80` before the segfault, along with the bogus numerical call number.